# Prefill textarea html element with xml data

Tags: html, xml, forms, encoding, textarea

I'm trying to write a static HTML page to post a big XML file to a server.
My page must contain a textarea in a form, prefilled with the XML data and the submit button. 
Is it possible to achieve this without using JavaScript? Do I have to URL-encode the value of the textarea with some tool and put inside the textarea the already encoded string? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to achieve this without using JavaScript?

Yes.

> Do I have to URL-encode the value of the textarea with some tool and put inside the textarea the already encoded string?

No. You have to HTML encode it. It's an HTML document, not a URL.

```html
<textarea>&lt;xml /&gt;</textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I managed to encode my huge xml string using the  System.Web class in a Powershell script and copying and pasting the encoded string inside the textarea in my  static HTML page.